# Max latitude for x distance from longitude - Max longitude for x distance from latitude - SQL

Tags: mysql, math, latitude-longitude

Right now I have a table of 100 million inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE o (
    id          int UNIQUE,
    latitude    FLOAT(10, 8),
    longitude   FLOAT(11, 8)

);
```

On my back end I am receiving a user lat/long and trying to return everything within x distance of that.

Instead of doing the distance formula on every single result I was thinking I could possibly calculate the maximum lat/long for X distance.

So we are sort of creating a square by finding the max lat/min lat, max long/min long.

Once we have these max values we would do the query on this range of values thus making our subset significantly smaller to then do the actual distance formula on (i.e., finding the values within X distance).

So my question to you is:
What makes me run faster?

Option 1)

- Distance formula on 100 million entries to get the set.

Option 2)

- Instead of doing the distance formula on the set of 100 million entries we calculate the min/max lat/long.
- Select the values in that range from the table of 100 million entries
- Do the distance formula on our new smaller set.

Option 3)

- Something exists already for this in SQL

If option 2 is faster the next issue is actually solving that math problem.

If you want to look at that continue reading:

Lat/Long distance formula

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a)) 
d = R * c
```

Obviously we can rearrange this because D (assume 1 mile), and R (is the radius of the earth) is a set value so we get D/R = C.

The problem then comes in to how do we calculate C/2 = atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Look at mysql spatial data types and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 -- 100M rows is a lot to scan and test.  It's OK do do once in a while, but it is too slow to do a lot.

2 -- Using a pseudo-square bounding box and doing

```
WHERE latitude  BETWEEN ...
  AND longitude BETWEEN ...
```

is a good first step.  The latitude range is a simple constant times X; the longitude range also divides by `cos(latitude)`.

But the problem comes when you try to find just those rows in the square.  Any combination of index on `latitude` and/or `longitude`, either separately or together, will only partially filter.  That is, it will ignore longitude and give you everything within the latitude range, or vice versa.  That might get you down to 100,000 rows to check the distance against.  That's a lot better than 100,000,000, but not as good as you would hope for.

3 -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng Does get down to the square, or very close.  It is designed to scale.  I have tested only 3M rows, not 100M, but it should work fine.

The main trick is to partition on latitude, then have longitude be the first column in the `PRIMARY KEY` so that InnoDB will cluster the nearby rows nearby in the partition(s).  If you look for all rows within X miles (or km) it might look at (and compute the great-circle-distance) for about twice as many rows as necessary, not 100K.  If you want to find the nearest 100 items, it might touch about 400 (4x).

As for `SPATIAL` index, you might want to upgrade to [5.7.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html), which is when `ST_Distance_Sphere()` and `ST_MakeEnvelope()` were added.  (MakeEnvelope is only marginally more convenient than building a Polygon yourself -- it has flat-earth syndrome.)